# Summarized punch shifts for overlapping clock outs and ins

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a file that contains all of the time punch shifts for each employee like so:

| employee | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 10:40:00.000 | 2022-10-23 14:00:00.000 |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 14:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 14:30:00.000 |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 14:35:00.000 | 2022-10-23 17:07:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 06:50:00.000 | 2022-10-23 12:00:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 13:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 15:30:00.000 |

However, I'm wanting to return a summarized row for each employee IF the clock-ins and clock-outs fall within overlapping hours like so

| employee | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 10:40:00.000 | 2022-10-23 17:07:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 06:50:00.000 | 2022-10-23 12:00:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 13:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 15:30:00.000 |

The reason why I want to do this is because I then am going to count employees that were part of a timeshift during a given period of time. Right now my query is counting duplicates because there are employees clocking out and clocking back in within the same hour.

This is my code for counting employees for each hour

```
WITH  Hours AS(
    SELECT 1 AS HOUR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT HOUR + 1 FROM Hours WHERE HOUR < 24
)
SELECT 
   CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) [DATE], 
   HOUR, 
   COUNT(Emp_Int) AS [Head Count]
FROM 
   Hours
LEFT JOIN 
   TIME_SHIFTS_TABLE T on HOUR BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME) AND DATEPART(HOUR, END_TIME)
GROUP BY 
   CAST(Start_Time AS DATE), HOUR
ORDER BY 
   CAST(Start_Time AS DATE), HOUR asc
```

This join works but is counting duplicates when an employee logs out and back in within the same hour.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Given the expected output is radically different than the one from the previous task, you should post a brand new question with the initial sample tables and this expected output. And include a reference to this post. Your problem may be most likely solved in a completely different way.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I've posted another question seperately

Comment: I've rollbacked latest changes applied to this post to avoid overlapping problems and keep this problem and answer coherent with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. One way of dealing with this kind of task is to

- first generate the partitions you need with a running sum,
- then apply aggregation with `MIN(start_time)` and `MAX(end_time)`.

You can craft a running sum by:

- checking when the difference between current start time and previous end time is bigger than 59 minutes, with `DATEDIFF`, hence flag with 1 if that's the case
- use a `SUM` window function over this flag, for each of your employee

Then you can just run the aggregation on your newly created partitioning.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, LAG(end_time) OVER(PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY start_time), start_time) >= 60 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END AS change_partition
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(change_partition) OVER(PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY start_time) AS partitions
    FROM cte
)
SELECT employee, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time 
FROM cte2
GROUP BY employee, partitions
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tBRFlZPo).

Comment: Again, thank you for your answer! Question... I'm running into an issue where employees that clocked in around 10pm, 11pm, or 12am are not getting rolled over to the next day for 1am, 2am etc. I know I failed to mention that but that's something I would like to account for.

Comment: I'm not sure I have well understood what you mean. Consider updating your post with this case, or create a new post that addresses this specific case, including in either cases both the updated sample table and expected output.

Comment: I've updated my question and included an updated demo