# Count employees that were clocked in for each hour of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a file that contains all of the time punch shifts for each employee like so:

| employee | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 10:40:00.000 | 2022-10-23 14:00:00.000 |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 14:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 14:30:00.000 |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 14:35:00.000 | 2022-10-23 17:07:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 06:50:00.000 | 2022-10-23 12:00:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 13:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 15:30:00.000 |
| 799 | 2022-10-23 18:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 18:30:00.000 |
| 799 | 2022-10-23 18:35:00.000 | 2022-10-24 10:30:00.000 |

My ultimate ask is to be able to know how many employees were clocked in during each hour of the day like so:

| Date | Hour | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-23 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 7 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 9 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 10 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 11 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 12 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 13 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 14 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 15 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 16 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 17 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 5 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 7 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 9 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 10 | 1 |

The way I had thought about tackling this problem was by generating a series of 24 hours and simply counting based on clock ins and outs (demo available at the end of post). An issue I initially ran into was that my query was counting duplicates for employees that would clock in and out within the same hour. This issue was solved by another question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138531/summarized-punch-shifts-for-overlapping-clock-outs-and-ins)

This part of the problem was solved by returning the following before baking it into my query like so:

| employee | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-10-23 10:40:00.000 | 2022-10-23 17:07:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 06:50:00.000 | 2022-10-23 12:00:00.000 |
| 541 | 2022-10-23 13:00:00.000 | 2022-10-23 15:30:00.000 |
| 799 | 2022-10-23 18:00:00.000 | 2022-10-24 10:30:00.000 |

However, after baking this solution into my existing query, I am getting counts for 10/23/2022 but nothing for 10/24/2022. That is, my query is not accounting for when an employee clocks in on one day and clocks out on the next.

Here's my attempted query:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
    employee        INT,
    start_time      DATETIME,    
    end_time        DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO tab VALUES
(123,       '2022-10-23 10:40:00.000', '2022-10-23 14:00:00.000'),
(123,       '2022-10-23 14:00:00.000', '2022-10-23 14:30:00.000'),
(123,       '2022-10-23 14:35:00.000', '2022-10-23 17:07:00.000'),
(541,       '2022-10-23 06:50:00.000', '2022-10-23 12:00:00.000'),
(541,       '2022-10-23 13:00:00.000', '2022-10-23 15:30:00.000'),
(799,       '2022-10-23 18:00:00.000', '2022-10-23 22:30:00.000'),
(799,       '2022-10-23 22:35:00.000', '2022-10-24 10:30:00.000');

SELECT * FROM tab

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, LAG(end_time) OVER(PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY start_time), start_time) >= 60 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END AS change_partition
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(change_partition) OVER(PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY start_time) AS partitions
    FROM cte
),

  Hours AS(
    
    SELECT 1 AS HOUR
    UNION ALL
    SELECT HOUR + 1 FROM Hours WHERE HOUR < 24

)
SELECT 
    CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) [DATE], 
    HOUR, 
    COUNT(Employee) AS [Head Count]
FROM 
    Hours

LEFT JOIN(

    SELECT 
        Employee, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time 
    FROM 
        cte2
    GROUP BY 
        Employee, partitions

) T on HOUR BETWEEN DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME) AND DATEPART(HOUR, END_TIME)

GROUP BY 
    CAST(Start_Time AS DATE), HOUR
ORDER BY 
    CAST(Start_Time AS DATE), HOUR asc
```

My current query returns only this:

| Date | Hour | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-23 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 7 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 9 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 10 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 11 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 12 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 13 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 14 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 15 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 | 16 | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 | 17 | 1 |

It should also return this:

| Date | Hour | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-24 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 3 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 4 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 5 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 7 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 8 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 9 | 1 |
| 2022-10-24 | 10 | 1 |

Perhaps there is a completely different approach that would be best but I've included a demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/yZ75XvvY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way of doing this is:

- generate your calendar first, using the [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function, beginning with your first date (of your choice, according to the data you have) and running on for 48 times at timestep 1 hour.
- left join calendar with your table and check when the calendar datetime is found between your employee's start and end datetime
- aggregate with `COUNT` your employees

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, value, '2022-10-23 00:00:00') AS cal_date
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 48, 1) 
)
SELECT cal_date, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT employee) AS headcount
FROM      calendar
LEFT JOIN tab
       ON calendar.cal_date BETWEEN tab.start_time AND tab.end_time
GROUP BY cal_date
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fFnZQFn1).

**Side Note**: It's never recommended to split your hours from the date. Prefer having a datetime field, instead of a date + integer for hours field. Reason is because SQL Server is able to handle a single datetime field in a better way, using the tools that it makes available for us to use.

---

If your SQL Server version doesn't have `GENERATE_SERIES` at your disposal, you can use a recursive query to generate your calendar:

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT CAST('2022-10-23 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS cal_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(hh, 1, cal_date) AS cal_date
    FROM calendar
    WHERE cal_date < '2022-10-25 00:00:00'
)
...
```

Recursion will begin from the value you set in the first part of the query (namely `CAST('2022-10-23 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)`) and will add up 1 hour for each call, till recursion stops at the filtering condition (`WHERE cal_date < '2022-10-25 00:00:00'`).

Check the demo with recursion [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mHUuZbb0).

Comment: Wonderful, however, is there a workaround for GENERATE_SERIES as I'm using SQL Server 2019 and not 2022. I realize I should have specified this

Comment: There's a way to do it in previous SQL Server versions. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the side note on preserving the date time to use the tools dedicated to these types of fields